# bulk api java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: bulk-api

Am trying to read 8 million records with only 1 column (ID) using Bulk API without PK chunking. while reading I am continuously getting Connection reset exception :

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(ChunkedInputStream.java:244)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:689)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3053)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:238)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:116)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
    at java.io.StreamTokenizer.read(StreamTokenizer.java:500)
    at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:625)
    at com.sforce.async.CSVReader.nextRecordLocal(CSVReader.java:188)
    at com.sforce.async.CSVReader.nextRecord(CSVReader.java:116)

From the salesforce UI i can download the response file which is of size 170MB, while reading in JVM I don't see any out of memory.

can anyone let me know how to ix this?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say from the stack trace, but it looks like it is trying to decompress the zip stream and process it as a CSV in on pass. Maybe you could focus on downloading the entire CSV to the local file system and then extract the records separately.

Comment: hi  Daniel Ballinger,
but this is taken care by the salesforce jar (wsc.jar) , how can we download the csv file ?

Comment: You could use the Bulk API directly rather than via the Salesforce jar. See [Using Bulk Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm). In  particular, the Bulk Query Results HTTP Request.

Comment: hi   @Daniel Ballinger, so you mean download the whole response to a tmp file and then start reading it , instead of submitting the input stream to CSVReader and reading ?

Comment: Yes, that is something you could try. Get all the CSV data down as fast as you can and store it on disk. Then process the CSV at your leisure. My assumption is that the delay in processing the CSV while simultaneously streaming it down is causing the socket to drop.

Comment: downloading the file to local and process it with the local file stream solved the issue. But, this issue could occur even downloading the the file to local.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you can minimize the likelihood of the `Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` exception occurring if you pull the data down from the response stream as fast as possible.

Focus first on downloading and storing the entire CSV to disk first. Then process the records in the CSV as required.

If you are still having issues with the download of the CSV, try adjusting the buffer size used to retrieve the response stream.